# How to pass TextBox value to URL.Action in MVC razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.Net MVC website and I want to pass a textbox value from view to controller using URL Action.

Below is my code,

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="products" width="100%">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>ProductId</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>ShortName</th>
          <th>ProductNamePrefix</th>
          <th>Minimum Count</th>
          <th>Add Product</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
         <tr>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortName)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductNamePrefix)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.TextBox("MinCount", item.MinimumCount, new {@class = "form-control" + " " + item.ProductId})
            </td>
            <td>
               @if (item.IfExists == true)
               {
                  <div class='isa_success'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>
               }
               @if (item.IfExists == false)
               {
                  <a href="@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Home", new { ProductId = item.ProductId, Name = item.Name, ShortName = item.ShortName, ProductNamePrefix= item.ProductNamePrefix, MinimumCount= item.MinimumCount})"><div class='isa_info'><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i></div></a>
               }
           </td>
        </tr>
      }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to pass the textbox value in url action method to controller. I am creating a custom class based on the id for textbox but I am not able to retrieve it using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Which textbox value? Does your AddProduct has a param to accept it ? What is it called ?

Comment: It is MinimumCount textbox and yes controller accepts this param. But it is always coming as null.

Comment: You want the initial value or updated value (user can edit the textbox value. rite ) ? Why are you not doing a form post ?

Comment: What does your controller action look like? You need to have some model set in your view and your post controller action needs to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I am not able to retrieve it using javascript or jQuery

Why not?  It's [pretty simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34994603/328193).

In the absence of JavaScript, you can't do this with just a link.  Instead, you'd need to use a form.  So you'd have to wrap each table row in a `form` element and replace your link with an `input type="submit"`.  (And, of course, style it according to your needs.)  This would post the values of the contained form elements (including the text box) to the form's action.

This does get *a little* ugly, since you can't wrap a `form` around a `tr`, so you'd have to *nest* your structure.  Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <table><!-- Your 1-row table goes here --></table>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The *outer* `tr` is what gets repeated for each row of your "table", so each row is actually a single cell containing a nested table which itself has only one row.  As I said, a bit ugly.  But it gets the job done.